# Developing a :NET library started by a MATLAB application

Tags: c#, .net

We are developing a .NET library, that has a WPF UI. This application is started by a MATLAB application and now we figured out, that some things behave different, when we start it from MATLAB, instead of starting it from our .NET mock application (`Application.Current` is `NULL` - maybe there are other differences). Since testing through MATLAB is a bit cumbersome (quit MATLAB, build project in VS, start matlab, set breakpoint in MATLAB function, run MATLAB function, attach VS to MATLAB, continue debugging in MATLAB): How can I setup a test application, that uses our library and behaves like our target system would do - that integrates better with VS?

Comment: Have you tried setting MatLab as the executable that is started when you debug? Check the debugging properties of the project.

Comment: .Net with Matlab. That's Cool! Any details/tutorial?